# Drag and drop upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to create a jquery drag and drop file upload plugin or use an existing one.

Unfortunately I cannot find any plugin that does exactly what I want to achieve.

Can someone point me a good place to search or how to start to implement my own file upload plugin?

Thanks.

I need the following functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The one should work perfectly for your needs. I have used it and it is pretty simple to configure and use.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Here are the features

- multiple file select, progress-bar in FF, Chrome, Safari
- drag-and-drop file select in FF, Chrome
- uploads are cancellable
- no external dependencies
- doesn't use Flash
- fully working with https
- keyboard support in FF, Chrome, Safari
- tested in IE7,8; Firefox 3,3.6,4; Safari4,5; Chrome; Opera10.60;

Answer (score 1):

also, you can try PLUpload (http://plupload.com/)
On that page you'll see that Drag&Drop is supported by HTML5, Gears(from Google) or BrowserPlus.

Note: Drag/drop support of files is currently only available in Firefox and WebKit. Safari on Windows has some strange problems and requires workaround.

In IE and/or Opera, that drag&drop could not work properly as you expected.